# Generate Radiobutton Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a button which generates radiobuttons but i would like to make a script which creates 2 radiobuttons in a div class.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x10wykzh/ (What i have now)

```
function test() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

I would like to create 2 radiobuttons when i click the first recangle. 
The radiobuttons have to be shown in the div class "drie" and i want to give it functions later on. 
Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

`In Jquery`

```
$('.content').click(function(){
    var html='<div class="drie">';
    for(var i=0 ; i<2; i++ ){
        html +='<input type="radio" name="drie"></input>';
       }
    html+='</div>';
    //alert(html);
   $('#radio').append(html);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvo9ajo6/)